# How to SELECT INTO newTable FROM subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are two tables with hundreds of columns, a and b.  I am trying to outter join them as a new third table, c.

```
SELECT * FROM a
FULL JOIN b
ON a.id=b.id
```

Since there are too many columns, it is not practical to CREATE TABLE first AND INSERT INTO.  There are some posts discussed about SELECT INTO, like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO c 
FROM (
     SELECT * FROM a
     FULL JOIN b
     ON a.id=b.id
     )
     ;
```

Error message:

```
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

There are many similar posts but none of them answers the question here.  Could anyone enlighten?

SELECT INTO: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: The table valued subquery MUST have alias (see below). It does not matter that you would not use it. Slightly offtopic, but you are using full join, in your post you are talking about outer join, and it somehow feels you actually need inner join. 

SELECT * 
INTO c 
FROM (
     SELECT * FROM a
     FULL JOIN b
     ON a.id=b.id
     ) T
     ;

Comment: "There are two tables with hundreds of columns ..." - it sounds like you *may* be solving the wrong problem. It's very rare, in my experience, for any table to need more than about 30 columns.

Answer (score 4):

You need to name the subquery:

```
SELECT * 
INTO c 
FROM (
     SELECT * FROM a
     FULL JOIN b
     ON a.id=b.id
     ) sub
```

But you don't really need a subquery to do that, a simple statement will work as well:

```
SELECT * 
INTO c 
FROM a FULL JOIN b
  ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Surely it could be as simple as SELECT * INTO c FROM a FULL JOIN..., too

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the comment.  If I add subquery 'sub' like your example, the following error message will show up: "The column 'product_class_id' was specified multiple times for 'sub'."

Comment: @Chubaka if you have multiple columns sharing the same name between your tables, there's no way for SQL Server to know how to name them in the new table. You need to provide aliases or only select the subset you need.

Comment: Ah I see. there are indeed many columns sharing the same name between  the two tables.

Comment: Hi Amit, could you explain more about "You need to provide aliases" in your above comments?  Thanks!

Comment: @Chubaka say you have a column col1 in both tables, you could use `SELECT a.col1 AS col1_a, b.col1 AS col1_b` to give them an alias and that will be used as the column names in the new table.

Comment: For one we know they both have a column named id

Answer (score 0):

You need to write commun column names between the two table just one time --for exemple:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
SELECT a.* /*all a colums*/, /*b.columns that don't exist in the table a */
FROM a 
FULL JOIN b 
ON a.id = b.id 
)AS C
```

Answer (score 0):

Column names must be unique and for sure each has ID
You get away with a pure select as it is just going to output
But as soon as it goes to even a sub-query it fails

```
select * from 
(
SELECT * FROM a
FULL JOIN b
ON a.id=b.id
) tt
```

You need to list list only only unique columns or use an alias to make then unique

What some people do is use the table name in the column so they will be unique.  e.g. aID, bID

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct, you are just missing an alias..

```
SELECT * INTO c
FROM ( 
      SELECT * FROM a FULL JOIN b ON a.id = b.id 
    )
AS tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, Japz! Error message:The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'tmp'.

Answer (score -3):

SELECT * 
FROM a OUTER JOIN b AS c ON a.id=b.id;